# Is their an existing method(s) in .Net C# that add up Gregorian duration to start date?

Tags: c#, .net, gregorian-calendar

I was looking for existing method(s) in .Net C# that add up [Gregorian duration ISO 8681](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) to start date to come up with end date.

For Example :

```
Start Date : 2007-03-01
Duration   : P1Y2M10D
End Date   : (Start Date + Duration) = 2008-05-11  // Pseudocode
           : P1Y2M10D + 2007-03-01 = 2008-05-11    // Actual Representation
```

Is their any existing method in .Net that already does it automaticaly before I manually do it on my own? *"Time handling is tricky so I preferred to use existing method if their any."*

**Note :** I researched for this functionality but can not find it in internet even in visual studio intellesence. I omitted other designator like Time (T) to reduced precision but it could be completed for example of complete duration is P1Y2M10DT2H30M.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) project is able to parse ISO-8601 durations as `Period` objects, which can then be used for calendrical arithmetic with `LocalDate` or `LocalDateTime` values. For example:

```
var pattern = PeriodPattern.NormalizingIsoPattern;
var text = "P1Y2M10D";
var start = new LocalDate(2007, 3, 1);
var period = pattern.Parse(text).Value;
var end = start + period;
Console.WriteLine("{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", end); // 2008-05-11
```

I don't believe there's anything in regular .NET which is equivalent.

Comment: I was hoping that their is already existing in .Net since it is standard but I'll try it out and let you know ASAP today. Thanks!

Comment: Also works with time precision. It saves me a lot of time. Awesome!